# Contenido Dinámico css grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Estoy trabajando haciendo una pagina web que muestra contenido consumiendo apis, y tengo un pequeño problema, el cual es que no logro que una de las secciones sea dinámica, a lo que me refiero es a lo siguiente:
Necesito que haya un máximo de 9 ofertas distribuidas de la siguiente manera en desktop min-widht 1200

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio si hay menos de nueve ofertas el contenido se adapte dinamicamente, por ejemplo, si hay 8 ofertas, que la ultima tome todo el ancho de la grilla.

Y mi código es el siguiente, el cual esta en codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-darkness-gp6j46?file=/index.html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
.ofertasDestacadas {
  width: 82%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%, 245px), 1fr));
  padding: 3.5rem 0;
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-auto-rows: 14rem;
}

.Galery__item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.Galery__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.Galery__h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.Galery__button {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .Galery__item:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column-start: span 2;
  }
  .Galery__item:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column-start: span 2;
  }
  .Galery__item:nth-child(7) {
    grid-column-start: span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
      <div class="ofertasDestacadas">
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://www.fundacion-affinity.org/sites/default/files/dia-de-los-animales.jpg"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Fotos-Divertidas-del-mundo-animal-P.png"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Fotos-Divertidas-del-mundo-animal-P.png"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Fotos-Divertidas-del-mundo-animal-P.png"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://arbolabc.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/Science/animals/articles/animales-domesticos/dog.jpg"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://eoc.cat/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/nuevos-animales-de-compania.jpg"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://eoc.cat/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/nuevos-animales-de-compania.jpg"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://www.hogarmania.com/archivos/202109/animales-felices-portada-1280x720x80xX.jpg"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Galery__item">
          <img
            src="https://www.consumer.es/app/uploads/2021/12/mascotas-conejillo-indias.jpg"
            alt=""
            class="Galery__img"
          />
          <h2 class="Galery__h2">imagen</h2>
          <button value="Call to action" class="Galery__button">
            Call to action
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Debes añadir aquí tu código CSS y HTML editando tu pregunta